# How I can return Affected rows data from post API in response oracle DB and Node JS

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, post

I'm using node js with oracle DB and i use post api to insert data I need to return the data inserted in the response , I tried result.affectedrows but this is coming with number of rows I need the data is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the returning clause with the SQL statement. Here's an example that gets an ID which is assigned by a trigger in the database:

```
const createSql =
 `insert into employees (
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    phone_number,
    hire_date,
    job_id,
    salary,
    commission_pct,
    manager_id,
    department_id
  ) values (
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :email,
    :phone_number,
    :hire_date,
    :job_id,
    :salary,
    :commission_pct,
    :manager_id,
    :department_id
  ) returning employee_id
  into :employee_id`;

async function create(emp) {
  const employee = Object.assign({}, emp);

  employee.employee_id = {
    dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
    type: oracledb.NUMBER
  }

  const result = await database.simpleExecute(createSql, employee);

  employee.employee_id = result.outBinds.employee_id[0];

  return employee;
}

module.exports.create = create;
```

That's a snippet from [a series that you might be interested in](https://jsao.io/2018/04/creating-a-rest-api-handling-post-put-and-delete-requests/).